# Can't access nm-applet through Applications menu on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, network-manager

On 16.04 I can invoke the nm-applet GUI using

```
Applications -> System Tools -> System Settings -> Network
```

However, nothing happens when I use this shortcut

```
Applications -> Other -> Network
```

I can see that the daemon is running

```
--> ps x | fgrep nm
 1257 ?        Sl     0:03 nm-applet
```

I think the daemon gets invoked on startup, but I want to be able to select the VPN connection etc. inside the GUI menu.
How do I make the shortcut work?

Comment: Another oddity, maybe related to this or not, is that I can use the GUI to connect to a VPN but the window says "Not connected".

I can confirm that I *am* connected because I can ssh into the remote subnet. Also a semi-visible pop-up says that the connection had been made.

But the GUI just says "Not connected" the whole time. I think conmands are being transmitted to the daemon but the GUI is not being updated.

Comment: Actually, retracting that comment -- it eventually reports "Connected" if I wait long enough.

Comment: I've added a launcher to my Main Menu that opens the Network panel directly, via "unity-control-center network". This works for my purposes, but doesn't solve the original problem of the other menu options not doing anything. Also there's the [problem that only one Unity pane can be visible at a time](http://askubuntu.com/questions/795626/16-04-multiple-unity-control-center-panels).

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to have gone away, the command

```
Applications -> Other -> Network
```

does pull up a network menu. It may have been fixed when I ran the command

```
sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade
```

which bumped-up my Ubuntu level to 16.04.2.